# Flutter doctor makes flutter upgrade complain about local changes

Tags: flutter

flutter upgrade says:

```
Your flutter checkout has local changes that would be erased by upgrading. If you want to keep these changes, it is recommended that you stash them via "git stash" or else commit the changes
to a local branch. If it is okay to remove local changes, then re-run this command with --force.
```

After clearing the changes, I run flutter doctor:

```
$ flutter doctor
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine b863200c37df4ed378042de11c4e9ff34e4e58c9...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  263M  100  263M    0     0  4774k      0  0:00:56  0:00:56 --:--:-- 5029k
Building flutter tool...
Downloading Material fonts...
Downloading android-arm-profile/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-arm-release/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-arm64-profile/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-arm64-release/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-x86 tools...
Downloading android-x64 tools...
Downloading android-arm tools...
Downloading android-arm-profile tools...
Downloading android-arm-release tools...
Downloading android-arm64 tools...
Downloading android-arm64-profile tools...
Downloading android-arm64-release tools...
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...
Downloading package sky_engine...
Downloading common tools...
Downloading common tools...
Downloading darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading libimobiledevice...
Downloading usbmuxd...
Downloading libplist...
Downloading openssl...
Downloading ideviceinstaller...
Downloading ios-deploy...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-BE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

And now flutter upgrade complains again about local changes.

Can someone please explain why, or what I am doing wrong ?

It doesn't make sense (at least to me) that flutter doctor would cause flutter upgrade to complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this can happen if you downloaded flutter as a zip instead of cloning the repository with git.

Removed the old flutter folder, ran git clone, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

try using `flutter upgrade --force` that worked for me when i had the same problem

Comment: It worked for the moment, but if you run flutter doctor and then try to update again, you get back to the initial problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe Flutter doctor is modifying to `<FlutterRoot>/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle` as it is downloading tools.

You can either commit the changes, and see if Flutter can do the merge. Or simply stash / ignore the changes.

The reason is simply: `git` which is not a bad thing though. Git refuses to pull in case an already-changing file is about to be updated: You can check more about merges in [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtrebase)

If you are askigng why the doctor would not commit its changes, then you are asking about a design choice that I do not know.

Comment: Even if I stashed the changes, this would keep happening. I just posted the solution: remove old folder, and use git clone to get flutter instead of downloading the zip.